# Long lasting tower for 70+ couple

Tags: desktop

A friend of mine desperately needs a new computer. His current device has lasted for over 10 years and I'm aiming for the new one to match this.

He and his wife have reached a respectable age. The device doesn't have to be top-of-the-line and should preferably 'run forever' without hassle. Which basically boils down to it should be able to perform basic tasks for as long as possible without requiring 2 minutes to launch a web browser, open a PDF or load a map with pictures.

Since, basically, that's all it's going to be used for.

Finding something meeting those (vague) criteria isn't hard. Finding something that will likely meet those criteria in 10 years is a different story. My guess is I should stick with the 'recent' tech and keep it simple.

So far I've found a tower for € 415, which is within budget (€ 450 preferred, € 500 tops) with the following:

- i3-6100 3.7 GHz CPU
- 4 GB DDR4-SDRAM (although I'm not 100% sure, this likely only occupies 1 of 2 RAM slots for easy/cheap extension to 2x4 GB)
- 240 GB SSD
- DVD-RW drive

[Epsilon Deluxe Systeem v2](https://www.afuture.nl/product/4868709/epsilon-deluxe-systeem-v2) (Dutch)

Hard requirements are at least 4th generation CPU 3 GHz, at least 4 GB RAM with room to extend, 200 GB HDD and an optical drive at least capable of reading DVD. But I think this is a nice fit for the other, vaguer requirements as well.

Am I missing something obvious in how I specified my target or does anyone have a better idea? Requiring assembly is not a problem, as long as I can be 100% confident it fits.

I haven't touched an i3 in years, but IIRC a use-case like this doesn't need anything higher.

I'm located in the Netherlands.

Comment: The i3-6100 is an awesome processor. I'm running on one in a *gaming* PC, so I'll guarantee that it'll be fine for what you're looking at.

Comment: That's essentially a good enough, easy to maintain system. I'd add a small secondary drive (say a 1tb laptop drive) and set up backups to that and double the ram if I was building it myself. I've never heard of teamgroup's SSDs so looking up some reviews would be nice.